# escaped special characters makes IIS 8 crash

Tags: php, iis-8

I've a **PHP** web application that needs to be running on **IIS** and I have a huge problem that I don't have on apache.

I have an **AJAX** call to go search in companies, it has the following structure:

```
http://localhost/fin/common/getCompanies/%26
```

The %26 is for "&", it's just an example. I have the same problem with all the accents, "+", etc.

I've searched online and found some things with double escaping, I tried it. Before the escaped "+" gave me a 404 and after it gave me a 500.

Is there a way to make it work like apache?

Comment: What is reported in the error logs for PHP and IIS? They should give you some clues.

Comment: Nothing in the php log and I couldn't find such thing as a IIS error log. Only the access log 

Comment: Hmm, Ok, But this is localhost - a development box. So, set it to tell you everything including notices. see: http://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7. PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display. Now, you need to change the settings on a production box - but for development you need to see every little error and fix it?  A 500 error is not a `crash`. It is just one very confused working machine. I develop on windows and get to see all the errors.

Comment: Maybe interesting? IIS Errors: [Viewing IIS Event and Error Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524984(v=vs.90).aspx).